# Integrate multivariable function with singularities using scipy.integrate.nquad

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration

I'm trying to integrate the function

```
def func(x, y):
    return 1 / np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)
```

with both x and y between -1 and 1 for which the numerical solution is roughly 7.05.

The problem is that there is a zero at the denominator for x=y=0 which I cannot understand how to handle it. I've been trying with the option points of integrate.nquad:

```
integrate.nquad(func, [[-1,1], [-1,1]], points = [[0],[0]])
```

but it doesn't seem the correct syntax. I found many examples (which I can reproduce) of integrating one variable function with singularities using the option point, but I don't understand how (and if it's possible) to generalize this with function of more than one variable. Looking at the manual doesn't help me unfortunately...

Comment: I guess one simple way to fix it would be to define your function so that if `x, y` are near the singularity, it returns 0.

Comment: Thanks; yes, indeed this a solution. I was just wondering if there was a way to use the points options for integrations in n>1 variables

Comment: Have you tried setting `opts=lambda x, y: {"points": ...}` or something similar to that? See also, the source code directly: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py

Comment: I've tried, but didn't succeed.. For the moment I'm just defining the function as suggested by Mateen to be zero when x is near y. I'll keep looking anywa

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
nquad(func, [[-1, 1], [-1, 1]], opts=[{'points': [0,]}, {'points': [0,]}])
```